# Cannot remove a dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
<div class='crumb'>sky</div>
<div class='crumb'>sea</div>
```

`sky` and `sea` are added dynamically using jQuery's `appendTo` function.

Now I want to remove all `crumbs` greater than then clicked one.
For example: `sky` is clicked, I expect `sea` to be removed.

```
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function() {
    var i = $(this).index(".crumb");
    $(".crumb:gt(i)").remove();
});
```

Nothing is removed!

Comment: @Taplar, because of breadcrumbs funcionality.

Comment: @charlietfl Seems fine to me. I mean other than the improperly concatenated variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).nextAll().remove();
```

Get all the elements after it and remove them

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function() {
   var i = $(this).index(".crumb");
   $(".crumb:gt("+i+")").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
<div class='crumb'>sky</div>
<div class='crumb'>sea</div>
```

Comment: My bad ... have used it for years but always the other way around. Just looked in api and didn't know could be done both ways. Have always used `$('.crumb').index(this)` .. another way to do same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function() {
   $(this).nextAll().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
<div class='crumb'>sky</div>
<div class='crumb'>sea</div>
```